# Firefox eventually for no aparent reason consumes all CPU and RAM and grinds to a halt pulling my computer along with it

Tags: firefox, ram, cpu, browser, crash

I now use Firefox as my default browser and have found that after having it up and running for several hours, that it starts to use up more and more of my CPU and RAM, and this does not appear to have any link to my activities (if any) in my browser. So now after having my browser up and running with 2 tabs open for 2 hours not doing very much my browser is using CPU 20, and RAM 1.2 GB (and often uses much more). But as my activities (reading stuff on a page) are very minimal I do not see why it should be using up so much RAM and CPU.

Is it just that Firefox is a much heavier browser and for some reason over time (even when there is no activity) slowly uses up more and more CPU and RAM and eventually grinds to a halt, bringing my machine with it, and meaning that unless it just crashes so much that eventually I just have to force quit it, or I restart it without it crashing too much, it will carry on until lightdm crashes, I am unable to switch to console to restart it, and I have to power down my machine manually and then restart? Or is there another reason why it could be happening? And if so, is there any way that I can diagnose what the issue is and hopefully fix it?

If you need any more information to answer my question, please just comment and I will happily do so.

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

### Package Information:

```
firefox:
  Installed: 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     37.0+build2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Not at all helpful, but that is a very literary title. I like it.

Comment: Does it still occur on 16.04?